# How to deal with exposure or outcome at time 0 in a time-varying Cox model

Tags: cox-model, time-varying-covariate

Let's say I have a dataset with a list of cars, some of which have self-driving function which is the time-varying exposure. Some of the cars had this function from the beginning (time 0) and some acquired it after. The outcome of interest is crash. Some cars had car crash day 0. How do you deal with these exposures and outcomes that occur at time 0 in a time-varying Cox-model?

Answer (score 0):

Cox regression doesn't model times-to-events directly; it only works with the ordering of events in time. Thus you can choose any positive value less than the smallest event time after `day 0` for event times on `day 0`. The baseline hazard function estimated at that chosen "event time" from the Cox model will then represent the cumulative hazard for events during `day 0`.